# How to create user activity logs?

Tags: php, mysql, logging, laravel, laravel-4

My goal is to keep track of activity logs when any users update their `username` or `email`.

I have `users` table in my database lay out like this :

- id
- username
- email

I decided to created a `logs` table that will contain :

- username
- username_new
- email
- email_new
- created_at
- user_id

After doing a bunch of researchs, some people suggested me to use `Event::fire` and `Event::listen`.

So … I been looking at [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events) again and again for awhile now.

I got this.

**For each action that a user takes should fire an event.**

---

```
$event = Event::fire(‘user.log’, array($user));
```

---

```
Event::listen(‘user.log’, function($user)
{

$log->username = $user->username;
$log->username_new = Input::get(‘username’);
$log->email = $user->email;
$log->email_new = Input::get(‘email’);
$log->created_at = Input::get('created_at');
$log->user_id = $user->id;

$log->save();

});
```

---

I know that I put these code in 
`app/start/global.php` OR `app/events.php`.

Well, I'm `NEW` to Laravel. But I believed that, "Every artist was once an amateur" - right ?

I'm not sure if my approach will work. BUT I hope that someone can point out if I did anything completely wrong, or possibly forgot anything.

Is what I am doing is logically make sense ?

HUGE `thanks` to everyone that contribute on this question !

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is? Have you tested your proposed solution?

Comment: Is what I am doing is logically make sense ?

Comment: Yes, though there is a logging class [built into Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#logging) Your solution appears to be fine if it meets your needs though.

Comment: There's already a package for storing data revisions: [link](https://packagist.org/packages/sofa/revisionable). Also, there is another one, that I've just created - a bit different and better https://packagist.org/packages/sofa/revisionable - It was created yesterday and still requires adding docs and some other stuff, but check the source to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer to your question (which you seem to have answered yourself), but: you might want to consider a more generic solution. For example, lets say you have an object `User` like this

```
User {
    protected $email;
    protected $username;
    protected $name;
}
```

When the user triggers a save, you trigger an event `user.change($oldUser, $newUser)` which, as param names suggest, propagate the user state before and after the change. You handle it with something like:

```
Event::listen('user.change', function($oldUser, $newUser) {
    // you could do a recursive diff here
    $diff = array_diff((array) $newUser, (array) $oldUser);

    // diff here contains only the changes made in that request
    // if you add more properties to user, they will work too
    // as there might be one or more properties in the diff, a non-prescribed columns
    // storage such as MongoDB might be a best choice
}
```

Food for thought in any way, HTH.